# What are these mysterious methods of a javascript exception?

Tags: javascript

I examined a javascript exception in Google Chrome.

[image]

And I noticed the functions `get message`, `get stack`, `set message`, and `set stack`. I tried catching this exception and running `alert(e.get_message());` only to get an error. I also tried to run `alert(e.get message());`, which obviously returned another error due to the space.

What are these mysterious methods, and how does a developer call them?

Comment: Note that property access via `.` is just syntactic sugar for indexing via `[...]`.  So you can, in fact, give an object a method with a space in its name; calling it would look like this: `alert(e['get message']());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're property accessors. They're effectively functions that run when you get or set the property.

```
e.message; // getter

e.message = "foobar"; // setter
```

Using property accessors, these do more than just a simple get and set of the property value. They can run code that was established in the object's property descriptors, so that the property access can have side-effects.

*Example:*

```
var o = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    foobar: {
        get: function() { return "getter"; },
        set: function(val) { alert("setter " + val); }
    }
});

o.foobar;  // "getter"
o.foobar = "raboof";  // alerts "setter raboof"
```

---

To see the property descriptors set for a given property, use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`...

```
console.dir(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(e, "message"));

Object
    configurable: true
    enumerable: false
    get: function getter() { [native code] }
    set: function setter() { [native code] }
```

Note that these techniques require an ECMAScript 5 supported implementation.